# Using MultipartContent - IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I receive this error when send post form-data to another api, with HttpClient :

[image: Error:]

I have this parameters on another api controller:

```
    public class IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// IdInteral do arquivo digital
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>1</example>
        public int IdInternalArquivoDigital { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Chave do Módulo
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>
        /// RecursosHumanos
        /// </example>
        public string ChaveModulo { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Versão do Módulo
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>
        /// 1.6
        /// </example>
        public int? Versao { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Versão dos Dados enviados para processamento
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>
        /// c8283005-68f5-41bf-aea6-29496068656c
        /// </example>
        public Guid IdProcessamento { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Colunas chaves
        /// </summary>
        public List<PayloadDTO> ColunasChaves { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tipo de operação - I,A,E
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>1</example>
        public string TipoOperacao { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Id arquivo Digital
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>1</example>
        public string IdArquivoDigital { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Nome Arquivo
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>teste.pdf</example>
        public string NomeArquivoDigital { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Arquivo
        /// </summary>
        public IFormFile Arquivo { get; set; }
    }


    public class PayloadDTO
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Nome do campo
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>
        /// Cidade
        /// </example>
        public string Campo { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Valor representativo do campo
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>José da Silva</example>
        public string Valor { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tipo do dado
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>int</example>
        public string Tipo { get; set; }

    }
```

And I this is controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Teste([FromForm] IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto dto)
{
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        WriteIndented = true,
    });

    return Ok(json);
}
```

I try using StringContent, Json , FormUrlEncodedContent And MultipartFormDataContent, but not working.

What is the correct way to make a post form-data using httpClient, with these parameters?

This is my implementation tests :

```
  [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:5001/teste";

            using (MultipartFormDataContent formDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                var obj = new
                {
                    IdInternalArquivoDigital = 3,
                    ChaveModulo = "RecursosHumanos",
                    Versao = 3,
                    IdProcessamento = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    ColunasChaves = new List<PayloadDTO>{
                        new PayloadDTO{
                            Campo="CdCategoria",
                            Tipo= "int",
                            Valor= "32",
                        },
                        new PayloadDTO{
                            Campo="Id",
                            Tipo= "int",
                            Valor= "3",
                        },
                        new PayloadDTO{
                            Campo="Nome",
                            Tipo= "strig",
                            Valor= "Samuel",
                        },
                    },
                    TipoOperacao = "I",
                    IdArquivoDigital = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    NomeArquivoDigital = "a7x.jg",
                };

                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true, });

                //json content
                // var jsonContent = new StringContent(json);

                // jsonContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
                // {
                //     CharSet = "utf-8"
                // };

                // Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                // dic.Add(nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.Versao), obj.Versao.ToString());
                // dic.Add(nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.IdArquivoDigital), obj.IdArquivoDigital.ToString());
                // dic.Add(nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.IdInternalArquivoDigital), obj.IdInternalArquivoDigital.ToString());
                // dic.Add(nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.IdProcessamento), obj.IdProcessamento.ToString());
                // dic.Add(nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.ChaveModulo), obj.ChaveModulo);
                // dic.Add(nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.NomeArquivoDigital), obj.NomeArquivoDigital);
                // dic.Add(nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.TipoOperacao), obj.TipoOperacao);

                // formDataContent.Add(new FormUrlEncodedContent(dic), "dto");

                // formDataContent.Add(new StringContent(obj.Versao.ToString()), nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.Versao));
                // formDataContent.Add(new StringContent(obj.IdArquivoDigital.ToString()), nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.IdArquivoDigital));
                // formDataContent.Add(new StringContent(obj.IdInternalArquivoDigital.ToString()), nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.IdInternalArquivoDigital));
                // formDataContent.Add(new StringContent(obj.IdProcessamento.ToString()), nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.IdProcessamento));
                // formDataContent.Add(new StringContent(obj.NomeArquivoDigital), nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.NomeArquivoDigital));
                // formDataContent.Add(new StringContent(obj.TipoOperacao), nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.TipoOperacao));
                // formDataContent.Add(new StringContent(obj.ColunasChaves.ToString()), nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.ColunasChaves));
                // formDataContent.Add(new StringContent(obj.ChaveModulo), nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.ChaveModulo));
                formDataContent.Add(new MultipartFormDataContent(obj.ChaveModulo), nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.ChaveModulo));

                string caminhoArquivo = @"C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Imagens\a7x.jpg";
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(caminhoArquivo, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
                            var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
                            //file content
                            // fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                            // {
                            //     FileName = "a7x.jpg"
                            //         .Replace("(", string.Empty)
                            //         .Replace(")", string.Empty)
                            //         .Replace(" ", string.Empty),
                            //     Name = "arquivo",
                            // };

                            formDataContent.Add(fileContent, nameof(IntegracaoArquivosDigitaisDto.Arquivo), "a7x.jpg");

                            _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

                            var res = await _client.PostAsync(url, formDataContent);

                            res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex) when (ex is HttpRequestException || ex is OperationCanceledException)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }

                }

            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting a good status of 200OK or a 400/500 error.  Normally when you get an error the body which in your case IActionResult is empty and will give an error.

Comment: @jdweng When I receive this error, status code is null.

Comment: Most likely this means one of two things 1) You are not getting a response and getting a timeout.  2) You got a response and got an exception doing the parsing before the status code was saved.  The status code should be saved before parsing.

Comment: You are serializing an `IFormFile` which isn't possible. Get rid of the debug code in the controller endpoint that is consuming the request.